# AWS ElasticBeanstalk + cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, devops, cloudflare

I have a question about setup AWS + Cloudflare

1) I have an instance on AWS Beanstalk with some public url like  xxx.zone.elasticbeanstalk.com

2) I decide to use cloudflare for: IPv6 support, SSL certificates, HTTP/2 support.

Is it enough to setup just CNAME records on cloudflare, or it is better to setting up direct IP to EC2 instance?

Do I need to close access to my EC2 instance via IP or Beanstalk public address?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it enough to setup just CNAME records on cloudflare, or it is
>   better to setting up direct IP to EC2 instance?

You should never use direct IP of Elastic Beanstalk instances because that IP is subject to change. Plus if you are using a load-balanced multi-instance Beanstalk configuration, you will need to use the load balanced DNS address, not an individual EC2 instance address.

> Do I need to close access to my EC2 instance via IP or Beanstalk
>   public address?

You would have to somehow block access to all IPs except CloudFlare IPs. Unless you have a list of every CloudFlare server IP (which would be a very large list) you won't be able to lock that down.

CloudFlare offers the [Argo Tunnel](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/argo-tunnel/) service if you want to lock down your origin servers so that only CloudFlare can access them.